# Eliminar espacio entre dos div

Tags: html, css, table

No sé porque aparece este problema. Estoy intentando crear algo asi como un registro de calificaciones, pero no quiero usar un **tablé**, por lo que opté por mejor usar **divs** y darles yo el formato.
Bien, el problema es que cuando intento poner un div al lado del otro y darles bordes para simular una tabla, entre los dos **divs** aparece un espacio que me molesta, intenté con el inspecionador de elementos, pero tal parece que entre ellos no existe nada. No sé qué podría ser...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es espacio entre las dos celdas rojas...

```css
.rowTable{
    display: block;
}
.rowTable .cell{
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 0px;
}
.rowTable .number{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 24px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.rowTable .nombre{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowTable">
 <div class="cell number">1</div>
 <div class="cell nombre">Ruiz Valdez Aldahir</div>
 <div class="cell rating"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso es el comportamiento de un inline-block, no tengo idea de la razón pero así se comporta.

Si tu juntas los divs sin espacio, bloqueas este comportamiento. Por ejemplo:

```css
.rowTable{
    display: block;
}
.rowTable .cell{
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 0px;
    margin-left:0;
    outline:0;
}
.rowTable .number{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 24px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.rowTable .nombre{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowTable">
 <div class="cell number">1</div><div class="cell nombre">Ruiz Valdez Aldahir</div><div class="cell rating"></div>
</div>
```

Ahora, si tú quieres simular una tabla, pienso que la mejor manera es hacer con css grid.

Ejemplo con css grid:

```css
.rowTable{
    display: grid;
    gap: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: 24px 250px 1fr;
}
.rowTable .cell{
    background: red;
    border-top: 1px solid blue;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.rowTable .cell:first-child{
    background: red;
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
}
.rowTable .number{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.rowTable .nombre{
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="rowTable">
 <div class="cell number">1</div>
 <div class="cell nombre">Ruiz Valdez Aldahir</div>
 <div class="cell rating"></div>
</div>
```

Acá tienes que fijarte en:

- grid-template-columns: 24px 250px 1fr;

Estas son las dimensiones de las columnas

- La primera 24px
- La segunda 250px
- La tercera 1fr --> Esto es básicamente a decir "el resto", o sea, si el with es de 300px el resto seria 26px

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a los espacios en blanco que existen entre cada "cell" dentro del div principal rowTable, si tomas este div contenedor e imprimís en consola todos sus elementos hijos no solo tenés las 3 celdas declaradas sino otros 4 elementos de tipo "textnode" que se crean automáticamente al tener espacios o saltos de línea entre las etiquetas. Una forma de solucionar esto es eliminando los espacios y los saltos de línea entre las etiquetas:

```
<div class="rowTable"><div class="cell number">1</div><div class="cell nombre">Ruiz Valdez Aldahir</div><div class="cell rating"></div></div>
```

Pero no queda demasiado bien. Otra solución para eliminar los "textnodes" que nos generan espacios misteriosos es usar un poco de Javascript y eliminar esos nodos y dejar solamente las 3 celdas que nos interesan:

```
const table = document.querySelector(".rowTable") // seleccion del contenedor principal
table.childNodes.forEach(element => { // para cada hijo del contenedor principal:
    if(element.nodeType==3) table.removeChild(element) // si el hijo es del tipo "textnode" (se representa con el 3) lo eliminamos de la lista de hijos del contenedor principal
});
```

Te recomiendo leer sobre los nodos y sus tipos. En este caso eliminamos los nodos de tipo "textnode" y dejamos solo los "elementnode". Espero que te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Bien. Gracias por su ayuda, encontré que al final tengo que usar mejor **Display:flex** para el padre y **display:inline-flex** para las celdas.
Es la mejor solucion.
Por otro lado, la opcion de usar grid si funciona, pero considero que ocupo menos lineas de codigo usando solo display:flex.
Y con respecto a lo de eliminar el **textNode** por alguna razon solo funciona en el primer elemento **rowTable** no se cual podria ser el problema, pero en las siguientes ROW no se aplica.

```css
.rowTable{
    display: flex;
}
.rowTable .cell{
    display: inline-flex;
    background: red;
    padding: 0px;
    gap: 0px;
    margin-left:0;
    outline:0;
}
.rowTable .number{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 24px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
.rowTable .nombre{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rowTable">
 <div class="cell number">1</div><div class="cell nombre">Ruiz Valdez Aldahir</div><div class="cell rating"></div>
</div>
```